# debian jessie install core server - without Libre Office and other software

Tags: debian-jessie

I'm unable to install debian (jessie) without libreoffice. Many website suggest many ways, but this libre office is like Internet Explorer in windows - it seems that you cant install system without it.

I've read bunch of articles how to remove libreoffice from debian (eg. https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/01/msg01224.html - still removal), but I would like to **install debian without LibreOffice** in the first place. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `netinst` image of Debian, that includes only the basic operating system without any desktop related packages.

Comment: Thanks; is it possible to install debian (full release eg with apache) without libreoffice or it is the only way? i'm not linux expert - what would be your approach to install debian + gui (eg lxde) + apache? would that still be netinstall + manual installation of each component?

Comment: Just use `apt-get install pkgname` to install apache2 and other needed packages after you have installed the basic system. You can search for particular packages with `apt-cache search name` command.